# Extract information of a JSON Angular 4

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have this JSON:

```
[{"id": "ARMpalmerillas07", "type": "GreenHouse","act_OpenVentanaCen": {"type": "float", "value": 0, "metadata": {"accuracy": {"type": "Float", "value": "07/02/2018 13:08 : 43 "}}},
"act_OpenVentanaLatNS": {"type": "float", "value": 0, "metadata": {"accuracy": {"type": "Float", "value": "07/02/2018 13:08 : 43 "}}},
"act_Aerotherm": {"type": "float", "value": 0, "metadata": {"accuracy": {"type": "Float", "value": "07/02/2018 13:08 : 43 "}}},
"act_BombaCalefaccion": {"type": "float", "value": 0, "metadata": {"accuracy": {"type": "Float", "value": "07/02/2018 13:08 : 43 "}}},
"var_ValvulaPpnalCalefaccion": {"type": "float", "value": 0, "metadata": {"accuracy": {"type": "Float", "value": "07/02/2018 13:08 : 43 "}}},
"var_VoltSensorTempSuelo3": {"type": "float", "value": 3, "metadata": {"accuracy": {"type": "Float", "value": "07/02/2018 13:08 : 43 "}}}}]
```

I'm not sure how to work with him, I would like to get the information in the HTML of `var_ValvulaPpnalCalefaccion.value`

I am working with the `.map (res => res.json ()) ;`. in the component and in the service

```
public datos: any = [];
this.datos = response;
console.log ('we show the headers:' + JSON.stringify (this.datos));
```

How can I assign the values ​​in a correct way:

At the moment I am with this:

```
public Tempext : ContextBrokerModels;
```

Model:

```
export class ContextBrokerModels {
  builder(
    public type: string,
    public value: string
  ) {}
}
```

```
this.Tempext = response [0] .var_ValvulaPpnalCalefaccion.value;
```

It is right?

Comment: try creating a reproduction of the issue. your code seems hard enough to debug otherwise - broken/non-continuous code in many places.

Answer (score 0):

You have an easy way. First, create a class ValvulaPpnalCalefaccion:

```
export class ValvulaPpnalCalefaccion{
    type: string;
    value: number;
    metadata = {};

    constructor(values: Object = {}) {
        Object.assign(this, values);
    }
}
```

Then in your service you can do:

`.map((res: Response) => res.json()[0].var_ValvulaPpnalCalefaccion.map(json => new ValvulaPpnalCalefaccion(json)));`

The return of this is an `Observable<ValvulaPpnalCalefaccion>`

Using this object, you can do what you want, in the html `{{variableValvula.value}}`

PD: The code above is not tested. I am using this way in [one of my projects](https://github.com/sttDB/sttDB-client), you can see a further example...

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply and for .map ((res: Response) => res.json () [0]) I did not know what could be done directly. but I really do not want to recover only var_ValvulaPpnalCalefaccion I want to recover all the values of that JSON .value to then assign it to my html so now I'm doing this:

this.Tempext = response.var_TempExt.value;
           this.Radext = response.var_RadiacionExt.value;
           this.RHext = response.var_HumRExt.value;
           this.Raining = response.var_Lluvia.value;
           this.WS = response.var_VVExt.value;

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. The solution you have is a possible one. Maybe I would try to create some classes. One called metadata which has attributes type and value and the other called jsonVar(change this name) which has attributes type, value, and an object metadata. Then you can use a list of this object to introduce it in the html using ngFor...

Answer (score 0):

```
//service
constructor(httpClient:HttpClient)
{}
getData()
{
      return this.httpClient.get("url").map(res=>res[0].var_ValvulaPpnalCalefaccion.value);
}
//Component
miService.getData.subscribe(res=>console.log(res));
```

Or

```
//service
constructor(httpClient:HttpClient)
{}
getData()
{
      return this.httpClient.get("url").map(res=>res[0]);
}
//Component
miService.getData.subscribe(res=>{
   console.log(res.var_ValvulaPpnalCalefaccion.value);
});
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer in case you want to recover all the values you would have to do this:

service:
return this._http.get (this.urlcontextBrokers, options) .map (res => res.json () [0]);


Component:
this.Tempext = response.var_TempExt.value;
           this.Radext = response.var_RadiacionExt.value;
           this.RHext = response.var_HumRExt.value;
           this.Raining = response.var_Lluvia.value;
           this.WS = response.var_VVExt.value;
           this.WD = response.var_DVExt.value;

It is right?

Comment: You're ok if you use the "old" http, if you use HttpClient, you needn't use res.json